# How to decrease timeout after which Touch Bar goes to sleep?

Tags: touch-bar

There is an option for keyboard backlight to be switched off after some timeout. I would like to do the same for Touch Bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently not possible to adjust the Touch Bar timeout.

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7820539